# Fill vector of pairs of doubles using XML string

Tags: c++, xml, c++11

I have an XML string such as the one below:

```
< thing TYPE="array" UNITS="meters">1.0,1.3,1.2,1.7,1.4,1.9< /thing>
```

I'm trying to put each pair of numbers into a `std::vector< std::pair< double,double > >`. It should look something like this when finished:

**< (1.0,1.3), (1.2,1.7), (1.4,1.9) >**

I know one way I could do this is search for each comma in the string to find the individual numbers and create a substring, then convert the substring to a double and fill one of the numbers in the pair. However, this seems like an overly complicated way to accomplish this task. Is there a simple way I could do this, maybe by using `std::istringstream`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it that single XML string you need to parse or there is something more? It there is something more then you should use some XML library. Otherwise, indeed you should be fine with `istringstream` .

Answer (score 0):

What about using `getline()`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> vpss;

   std::string str1, str2;

   std::istringstream iss("1.0,1.3,1.2,1.7,1.4,1.9");

   while ( std::getline(iss, str1, ',') && std::getline(iss, str2, ',') )
    {
      std::cout << str1 << ", " << str2 << std::endl;

      vpss.emplace_back(std::stod(str1), std::stod(str2));
    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Another solution could be put the comma in a `char` variable

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> vpss;

   char   ch;
   double d1, d2;

   std::istringstream iss("1.0,1.3,1.2,1.7,1.4,1.9");

   while ( iss >> d1 >> ch >> d2 )
    {
      std::cout << d1 << ", " << d2 << std::endl;

      vpss.emplace_back(d1, d2);

      iss >> ch;
    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to capture the data you want, and `std::stringstream` to parse it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    auto xml_str = R"(< thing TYPE="array" UNITS="meters">1.0,1.3,1.2,1.7,1.4,1.9< /thing>)"s;
    auto r       = regex(R"(>(\d.*\d)<)"s);
    auto m       = smatch{};
    auto vec     = vector<pair<double, double>>{};

    // Determine if there is a match
    auto beg = cbegin(xml_str);
    while (regex_search(beg, cend(xml_str), m, r)) {
        // Create a string that holds the 1st capture group
        auto str = string(m[1].first, m[1].second);
        auto ss = stringstream{str};
        auto token1 = ""s;
        auto token2 = ""s;
        auto d1 = double{};
        auto d2 = double{};
        // Parse
        while (getline(ss, token1, ',')) {
            getline(ss, token2, ',');
            d1 = stod(token1);
            d2 = stod(token2);
            vec.emplace_back(make_pair(d1, d2));
        }
        // Set new start position for next search
        beg = m[0].second;
    }

    // Print vector content
    auto count = 1;
    for (const auto& i : vec) {
        if (count == 3) {
            cout << "(" << i.first << ", " << i.second << ")\n";
            count = 1;
        } 
        else {
            cout << "(" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "), ";
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

(Compile with `-std=c++14`)

Output:
`(1, 1.3), (1.2, 1.7), (1.4, 1.9)`

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/HRTUVQ95145)